# Fourier series of $[x]-x+\frac{1}{2}$: Rigorous justification.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, fourier-series

> We have the Fourier series 
>   $$ [x]-x+\frac{1}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2 \pi n x }{n \pi }. $$ 
>   where $x$ is not an integer.

How is this **rigorously** justified? Are there any references?

---

My thoughts:

1. **We suppose $f(x)$ can be written in the form  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k \sin 2 \pi k x$  and the series is locally uniformly convergent,** as $f$ is $1$-periodic, we have

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \sin 2 \pi n x =  c_n \int_0^1 (\sin 2  \pi n x )^2 \, dx = \frac{c_n}{2} \Rightarrow c_n = \frac{1}{n \pi }$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor -x-\frac{1}{2}$ is a $1$-periodic function with a Fourier sine series given by
$$\lfloor x\rfloor -x-\frac{1}{2} \stackrel{L^2}{=} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{n\pi}\tag{1} $$
since $2\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\sin(2\pi n x)\,dx = \frac{1}{n\pi}$. On the other hand the RHS of $(1)$ is pointwise convergent for any $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ by summation by parts, since
$$ \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(2\pi n x)\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(\pi N x)\sin(\pi(N+1)x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\right|\leq\left|\cot\frac{\pi x}{2}\right|\tag{2}$$
hence the RHS of $(1)$ is pointwise convergent for any $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.
The convergence on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is not uniform due to [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).
However $(2)$ gives that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{\pi n}$ is uniformly convergent over any interval of the form $I_a=[a+\varepsilon,a+1-\varepsilon]$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. A uniformly convergent series of continuous functions gives a continuous function, hence over $I_a$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{\pi n} \stackrel{\text{unif.}}{=} g(x) \in C^0(I_a) \tag{3}$$
and by $(1)$ it follows that $\int_{I_a}(f(x)-g(x))^2\,dx = 0$. Since $f(x)\in C^0(I_a)$ it follows that $g(x)\equiv f(x)$, hence the convergence given by $(1)$ is also a pointwise convergence over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

This is just the [Fourier series of a Bernoulli polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series).

Comment: I see from the bound that the RHS is uniformly convergent on $[n+\varepsilon,n+1-\varepsilon]$. But how do you know the RHS converges to the LHS?

Comment: @CWL: the difference between the RHS and the LHS of $(1)$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$, hence if the RHS is pointwise convergent on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ and uniformly convergent on $[n+\varepsilon,n+1-\varepsilon]$, it is convergent to the LHS, since the LHS is continuous on $[n+\varepsilon,n+1-\varepsilon]$, a uniformly convergent series of continuous functions is a continuous function and the only continuous function over $[n+\varepsilon,n+1-\varepsilon]$ whose square has integral $0$ is the zero function.

Comment: @CWL: I updated my answer including details.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still have one more problem, why does the RHS and the LHS converge to $0$ in $L^2$?

Comment: @CWL: it is $RHS(1)-LHS(1)$ that converges to $0$ in $L^2$, since the RHS is the Fourier sine series of the LHS.

Comment: Yes, but why is that implied?  Is it something along the lines of Theorem 4.13 here: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~awilkie/newfourier4.pdf
Also, even if we have $\int |s_n -f | ^2  \rightarrow 0 $, why can we deduce $\int |s-f|^2  =  0$ (I guess we apply some sort of DCT)?

Comment: @CWL: that just follows from Parseval's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to recall that:

$$\ln(re^{i\theta})=\ln(r)+i\theta$$

$$-\ln(1-e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in\theta}}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)}n$$

Now take imaginary parts:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n\theta)}n=\Im(-\ln(1-e^{i\theta}))=\dots$$

Assuming $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$.  For $\theta\notin(0,2\pi)$, it results in a periodic like function...

Comment: Why is this beautiful answer downvoted?

Comment: Whoops lol, didn't even notice... I want notifications for downvotes...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, may you elaborate more fully on a full proof ?

Comment: @CWL What parts are you interested in?  The evaluation of the imaginary parts?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, actually I am confused: (i) $Ln(1+x)$ power series converges for $|x|<1$, also, yes, how did you evaluate the imaginary parts? I somehow always get one more constant on the RHS (one more $\pi/2$). Sorry for causing the trouble. Thanks.

Comment: @CWL That is not true.  Take $x=1$.  It is well known that:
$$\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$$

Comment: To extract real and imaginary parts of a logarithm, note that:
$$\ln(x+iy)=\ln|x+iy|+i\operatorname{atan2}(x,y)$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, thanks a lot, how do you know the RHS converges for general $e^{i \theta}$ , $\theta \in (0,2 \pi)$ though?

Comment: @CWL It follows from our choice of branch cuts.  By defining $-\ln(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}n$, we've chosen the branch we are going to use, hence why the value of $\theta$ comes out like that.

Comment: By this choice of branch cut, we only guarantee convergence for $|z|<1$ right? Here $|e^{i \theta}|=1$ though

Comment: @CWL as I have already said, it can converge for some $|z|=1$, and I've already provided you with an example of one such $z$.  What makes you believe it can't converge for $|z|=1$?

Comment: What I mean is don't you have to show this for all such $|e^{i \theta} |=1$ with $\theta \in (0, 2 \pi )$ and not just one value? Anyways, I upvoted your answer, maybe I should come review this post some time in future.

Comment: @CWL Yes, we do need to show that it holds... which it does.  For starters, it converges by Dirichlet's test, and as it converges, it converges to the logarithm as we'd expect (small handwave that when a Taylor expansion converges at the radius of convergence, it converges to the original function)

Comment: @user1952009 I do not believe *I* must prove it, and I've given CWL most of the tools necessary to do so.

Comment: You need to define and prove rigorously the convergence and the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in \theta}}{n}$ for $\theta$ real. IMO the idea is that for $|z| = 1, z \ne 1$ : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n} = \lim_{r \to 1-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (rz)^n}{n}=\lim_{r \to 1-} -\log(1-rz)$ @ SimplyBeautifulArt @CWL

Comment: @user1952009 Hm, I'm not quite sure where I've suggested it should work for any $\theta$.  As far as the context goes, I do believe CWL and I agree we are looking at $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Where you didn't mention the branch of $\log$ used for $-\log(1-e^{i \theta})$, which is the major problem

Comment: @user1952009 If you use the Ctrl+F command, you'll be able to search for the word "branch" on this page.  Hopefully it'll help you find where I've mentioned the branch of the logarithm.

Comment: Then where you didn't mention $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \log(1-r z)$. It is the same.

Comment: @user1952009 It appears you are only interested in making unnecessary comments.  While the content of your words are useful, I suggest you also take the time to read other comments as well.  As for your suggestion that I should justify that $\sum_1^\infty e^{in\theta}/n$ converges to $-\ln(1-e^{i\theta})$, one only needs to incite Abel's theorem, which is the ["small handwave" I've previously mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348342/fourier-series-of-x-x-frac12-rigorous-justification/2348354?noredirect=1#comment4837428_2348354).

Comment: Think more about it, you'll see why it is not unnecessary. If you don't want to discuss about maths, don't come on MSE.

Comment: @user1952009 It's not that I don't want to discuss math.  It's that this conversation is unnecessary.  If you want to chat so much, I recommend the chat rooms.  Also, conversations should be two-sided.  If you won't read my previous comments and make me repeat myself repeatedly, then take it in return that I shouldn't have to read or respond to yours (though I have)

Comment: @CWL I suppose if you are still having trouble, some of the above conversation may prove useful.